# Whats wrong with my C# program?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to create an application that fills an array with random numbers. I written the whole code and it works but the numbers are not displaying in the console window. What could be wrong with the code? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Arrays
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[10]; 
            Random randomNumbers = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                int randomValue = randomNumbers.Next(0,500);
                array[i] = randomValue;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The array value is: ", array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm dumb... I always miss that part.

Answer (score 6):

You can either use

```
Console.WriteLine("The array value is: {0}", array[i]);
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine("The array value is: " + array[i]);
```

but what you wrote,

```
Console.WriteLine("The array value is: ", array[i]);
```

entirely misses on telling the console where and how you use the array[i] variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
Console.WriteLine("The array value is: {0}", array[i]);
```

You have to indicate in the format string that you want to print some value.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Console.WriteLine("The array value is: ", array[i]);
  Console.WriteLine("The array value is: {0}", array[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Console.WriteLine("The array value is: {0}", array[i]);

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

After `Console.WriteLine();`

As others have mentioned, to get this line to work with `{0}`, you'd need to format it as a string,

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The array value is: {0}", array[i]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Coefficient Of x (Positive): ");
            int coef = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter Value Of c: ");
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("From? (Positive)");
            int from = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("To? (Positive)");
            int to = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Clear();
            int[] y_val = new int[(to - from) + 1];
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = to; i >= from; i--)
            {
                y_val[counter] = ((coef * i) + c);
                counter++;
            }
            int x = 0;
            for (int i = to; i >= from; i--)
            {
                if (y_val[x] == ((coef * i) + c))
                {
                    if (y_val[x] >= 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}|", y_val[x]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("0{0}|", y_val[x]);
                    }
                    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("  ");
                    }
                    Console.Write("*");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                }
                x++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("______________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication36
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("asd");
        }
    }
}
```